# How can I fix 503 error after changing permalinks structure in WP?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am just a beginner in WP and have a trouble 
when I change the structure of post's permalink in settings:

from **plain** "**domainname.com/?p=123**" to for example **post-name** structure "**domainname.com/sample-post**" (or any other structure), all my posts get 503 error.
When I change it back to plain, they work properly.

How I can fix it? According to some guides I have already deleted inactive plugins and themes, but I think they didn't even related to my problem.

## Thnx!

The problem **was solved** by some configuration of nginx/conf.d file.

Comment: Have you enabled WP_DEBUG to see if that gives you any extra information?

Comment: Yes, just right now. But it doesn't still work after permalinks structure changing. Moreover, i have 2 new warnings: 1). my site is set to log errors to a potentially public file (The value, WP_DEBUG_LOG, has been added to this website’s configuration file. This means any errors on the site will be written to a file which is potentially available to normal users). 2).  The REST API encountered an expected result (503)